# The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted after update ubuntu to 22.04.1LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu

After upgrading Ubuntu 20.04.4LTS to 22.04.1LTS, pgAdmin4 doesn't work. Please help me to solve this problem, there are several similar topics, none helped. I'm a beginner in using Ubuntu, maybe I did something wrong.

**The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:**

```
Total spawn time to start the pgAdmin4 server: 0.004 Sec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py", line 38, in <module>
    import config
  File "/usr/pgadmin4/web/config.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pgadmin.utils import env, IS_WIN, fs_short_path
  File "/usr/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, abort, request, current_app, session, url_for
  File "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from markupsafe import escape
  File "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/markupsafe/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import typing as t
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing'
```

Comment: Did [THIS QUESTION](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1212595/pgadmin4-got-removed-after-upgrading-from-ubuntu-18-04-to-19-10) pop up on your radar?

Comment: I try this solution but I can install pgAdmin4 without problem, but it doesn't work. The problem maybe with python because there is python 3.8 above, after upgrade system i have python 3.10.

Comment: PgA4 is only going to work with Python 3.8 ..  unless I've misunderstood the documentation..  you need to revert to 3.8

Comment: I downgrade Python from 3.10 to 3.8 and pgAdmin4 works again :-D Thank you for advice!                                                                                                                                                        sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.8